# how to programming teltonika device fmb 120 by Messages?

Tags: javascript, python, c#, teltonika

I own a Teltonika FMB120, so how is it programmed by SMS?
I'm trying to program the device through messages, and I'm not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have the physical device to hand, you can use their [Configurator software](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Teltonika_Configurator_versions) to set the parameters for the reporting etc.

Remotely they **do** have an API (of sorts), using their [Parameter List](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Template:FMB_Device_Family_Parameter_list) (FMB series, Codec dependent too. You can find which Codec is being used in the `Header` after you perform the initial handshake).

the API for remote configuring is painful to say the least.

Comment: Thank you 
but there is another way to program it remotely by sending him messages with SMS like setparam 2001:APN;2002:APN_username;2003:APN_password;2004:Domain;2005:Port;2006:0"

Comment: Yes that's what I mean about the parameter list. If you break down the command you posted, Param ID 2001 is the APN, Param ID 2002 is the APN Username etc. You can adjust all settings using the param IDs, but the documentation for them isn't great. It's best to do it off the configurator, and adjust things slightly remotely if possible. I've done it hundreds of times with Teltonikas :)

Comment: Yes 
Is there any video showing how to upload and program?

Comment: @ehabsonny not that I ever found - it was a very manual learning process. Teltonika have a forum too if you have specific questions, their support staff are fairly quick at responding too.